# Using pyuniswap.py and web3.py transaction error

Tags: web3js, web3.py

I am using pyuniswap.py to trade on BSC. This worked perfectly till I tried the sell() function. Every sell transaction failed.

This does not happen with the buy() function. I think the error must be somewhere in creating the transaction in the pyuniswap.py file. Does somebody know why this does not work? I am just calling the sell function with the calculated balance of the coin.

This is the full code off pyuniswap.py. I only changed the ETH_ADDRESS and the provider adress:

```
class Token:
# CHANGED WITH ADDRESS OF BNB
ETH_ADDRESS = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c')
MAX_AMOUNT = int('0x' + 'f' * 64, 16)

def __init__(self, address, provider=None):
    self.address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(address)
    self.provider = os.environ['PROVIDER'] if not provider else provider
    self.web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(self.provider))
    self.wallet_address = None
    # CHANGED WITH ADDRESS OF PANCAKE V2
    self.router = self.web3.eth.contract(
        address=Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e'),
        abi=json.load(open(
            os.path.abspath(f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/abi_files/" + "router.abi"))))
    self.erc20_abi = json.load(
        open(os.path.abspath(f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/abi_files/" + "erc20.abi")))
    self.gas_limit = 1500000

def connect_wallet(self, wallet_address='', private_key=''):
    self.wallet_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(wallet_address)
    self.private_key = private_key

def is_connected(self):
    return False if not self.wallet_address else True

def require_connected(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_connected():
            raise RuntimeError('Please connect the wallet first!')
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

def create_transaction_params(self, value=0, gas_price=None, gas_limit=None):
    if not self.is_connected():
        raise RuntimeError('Please connect the wallet first!')
    if not gas_price:
        gas_price = self.web3.eth.gasPrice
    if not gas_limit:
        gas_limit = self.gas_limit
    return {
        "from": self.wallet_address,
        "value": value,
        'gasPrice': gas_price,
        "gas": gas_limit,
        "nonce": self.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(self.wallet_address)
    }

def send_transaction(self, func, params):
    tx = func.buildTransaction(params)
    self.signed_tx = self.web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=self.private_key)
    return self.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(self.signed_tx.rawTransaction)

@require_connected
def is_approved(self, token_address=None, amount=MAX_AMOUNT):
    token_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_address) if token_address else self.address
    erc20_contract = self.web3.eth.contract(address=token_address, abi=self.erc20_abi)
    approved_amount = erc20_contract.functions.allowance(self.wallet_address, self.router.address).call()
    return approved_amount >= amount

@require_connected
def approve(self, token_address, amount=MAX_AMOUNT, gas_price=None, timeout=900):
    if not gas_price:
        gas_price = self.web3.eth.gasPrice
    token_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_address)
    erc20_contract = self.web3.eth.contract(address=token_address, abi=self.erc20_abi)
    func = erc20_contract.functions.approve(self.router.address, amount)
    params = self.create_transaction_params(gas_price=gas_price)
    tx = self.send_transaction(func, params)
    self.web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx, timeout=timeout)

def price(self, amount=int(1e18), swap_token_address=ETH_ADDRESS):
    swap_token_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(swap_token_address)
    return self.router.functions.getAmountsOut(amount, [self.address, swap_token_address]).call()[-1]

def received_amount_by_swap(self, input_token_amount=int(1e18), input_token_address=ETH_ADDRESS):
    input_token_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(input_token_address)
    return self.router.functions.getAmountsOut(input_token_amount, [input_token_address, self.address]).call()[-1]

def balance(self, address=None):
    address = self.wallet_address if not address else Web3.toChecksumAddress(address)
    if not address:
        raise RuntimeError('Please provide the wallet address!')
    erc20_contract = self.web3.eth.contract(address=self.address, abi=self.erc20_abi)
    return erc20_contract.functions.balanceOf(self.wallet_address).call()

@require_connected
def buy(self, consumed_token_amount, consumed_token_address=ETH_ADDRESS, slippage=0.01, timeout=900, speed=1):
    gas_price = int(self.web3.eth.gasPrice * speed)
    consumed_token_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(consumed_token_address)
    received_amount = self.received_amount_by_swap(consumed_token_amount, consumed_token_address)
    min_out = int(received_amount * (1 - slippage))
    if consumed_token_address == self.ETH_ADDRESS:
        func = self.router.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(min_out, [consumed_token_address, self.address],
                                                           self.wallet_address, int(time.time() + timeout))
        params = self.create_transaction_params(value=consumed_token_amount, gas_price=gas_price)
    else:
        if not self.is_approved(consumed_token_address, consumed_token_amount):
            self.approve(consumed_token_address, gas_price=gas_price, timeout=timeout)
        func = self.router.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(consumed_token_amount, min_out,
                                                              [consumed_token_address, self.address],
                                                              self.wallet_address, int(time.time() + timeout))
        params = self.create_transaction_params(gas_price=gas_price)
    return self.send_transaction(func, params)

@require_connected
def sell(self, amount, received_token_address=ETH_ADDRESS, slippage=0.01, timeout=10000, speed=1):
    gas_price = int(self.web3.eth.gasPrice * speed)
    received_token_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(received_token_address)
    received_amount = self.price(amount, received_token_address)
    print("received_amount: " + str(received_amount))
    min_out = int(received_amount * (1 - slippage))
    if not self.is_approved(self.address, amount):
        self.approve(self.address, gas_price=gas_price, timeout=timeout)
    if received_token_address == self.ETH_ADDRESS:
        func = self.router.functions.swapExactTokensForETH(amount, min_out, [self.address, received_token_address],
                                                           self.wallet_address, int(time.time() + timeout))
    else:
        func = self.router.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(amount, min_out,
                                                              [self.address, received_token_address],
                                                              self.wallet_address, int(time.time() + timeout))
    params = self.create_transaction_params(gas_price=gas_price)
    return self.send_transaction(func, params)
```

This is the message I get: [image]